# Vanilla Javascript: How to add multiple event listeners to buttons which are dynamically created with same class in django?

Tags: javascript, django, dom-events, addeventlistener

I am currently working on a project 4 for CS50w - Network. One of the tasks is to add an edit posts button (for editing the posts that logged in user (only owner) created), which does this async. Since for storing posts I'm using Django Models, I'm using Django (and it's template capabilities) to display all the posts to users too, and an edit button (if user is the creator of the post too). I'm displaying all the posts in a div. This means that the button for editing is also a part of this div... meaning that I can give it only single class or id for referencing, but then I don't know how to distinguish between them, and how to know which one (from which post) is clicked so that I can edit that post and not the first one on which the JS in DOM comes up... Anyways here's the code:

HTML in Django:

```
{% for post in posts %}
        <div class="post">
            <a href="{% url 'users' post.user.username %}">{{ post.user }}</a>
            <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
            <p>{{ post.created }}</p>
            {% if user.is_authenticated and user == post.user %}
                <button class="edit_post_button">Edit Post</button>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="edit_post" style="display: none;">
            <a href="{% url 'users' post.user.username %}">{{ post.user }}</a>
            <textarea rows=3 cols=20>{{ post.content }}</textarea>
            <p>{{ post.created }}</p>
            <button class="save_edit_post_button">Save</button>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
```

and here is the little JS that I wrote that doesn't work (I'm just starting to learn it, and would like to finish this project with vanilla JS):

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        document.querySelectorAll('.edit_post_button').forEach(edit_post_button => {
            edit_post_button.addEventListener('click', edit_post);
        })
    });
    
    function edit_post(event) {
        document.querySelector('.post').style.display = 'none';
        document.querySelector('edit_post').style.display = 'block';
    }
```

Comment: Where is `<edit_post>` tag in your markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delegation is the answer

Note you forgot a dot in `document.querySelector('edit_post')`

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.getElementById('postContainer').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target.closest('.edit_post_button')
    if (tgt) {
      const postDiv = tgt.closest('.postDiv')
      postDiv.querySelector('.post').hidden = true
      postDiv.querySelector('.edit_post').hidden = false
      console.log(tgt.dataset.id); // if needed
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="postContainer">
  <div class="postDiv">
    <div class="post">
      <a href="User1URL">user 1</a>
      <p>Post 1 </p>
      <p>yesterday</p>
      <button class="edit_post_button" data-id="postId1">Edit Post</button>
    </div>
    <div class="edit_post" hidden>
      <a href="User1URL">user 1</a>
      <textarea rows=3 cols=20>Post 1</textarea>
      <p>Yesterday</p>
      <button class="save_edit_post_button">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="postDiv">
    <div class="post">
      <a href="User2URL">user 2</a>
      <p>Post 2 </p>
      <p>yesterday</p>
      <button class="edit_post_button" data-id="postId2">Edit Post</button>
    </div>
    <div class="edit_post" hidden>
      <a href="User2URL">user 2</a>
      <textarea rows=3 cols=20>Post 2</textarea>
      <p>Yesterday</p>
      <button class="save_edit_post_button">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But now I have new 'problem' :|  I don't know how to make sure that after clicking save (and after my db was updated on the backend) I 'reload' this post only with new content in it ... my logic works (fetch updates the content) and I use .then to again hide the edit div and show the orig post div, but only after i refresh the page I get the new content in the post too..  probably something to do with my .then logic ... Anyhow, if you can help here too, would be amazing! Anyhow, thanks for your help !

Comment: you did not post any fetch. Perhaps a new question?

Comment: Yeah, it wouldn't let me, but I figured it out. Thanks !!